# "was-was" or "was-is"

Tags: grammar, phrases

Which one is correct?

> I was wondering if it {**was**|**is**} not too late to ask if you could give me ...

Comment: well .. the second one.  I would have thought.

Comment: The first one makes more sense grammatically, but "I was wondering" is often used as a substitute for "Excuse me, please," - so, people pretty much say anything after it, (US)

Comment: As @Oldbasg says, but forms do occur. Bear in mind the *I was wondering* (or more often, just *I wonder*) part is effectively just meaningless "mumbling" to give the person you're addressing time to start paying attention (equivalent to clearing one's throat, for example). And in most cases the *not too late to ask* part is equally irrelevant. In a "work email" context where you don't want to waste the other person's time, I'd stick to plain ***Could you give me...***

Comment: Dear Greg, I am extremely sorry that on your first visit you should have been mauled by an editor, criticised by a contributor who has no appreciation of nuance, and down-voted by an anonymous critic,  There is another linguistics site.

Comment: @Hugh did you see the original version of the question? Granted, that was a radical edit, but it made the post much clearer and corrected the various spelling errors to boot. It also added a (marginally) more useful title. I'd hardly call this "mauling"

Answer (score 2):

The first one makes more sense grammatically, but "I was wondering" is often used as a substitute for "Excuse me, please," - so, people pretty much say anything after it. (US):

"*I was wondering/Excuse me, please*...

... is this the line for the ladies' room?

... has Elvis left the building?

... was that you, kicking me under the table?

... could I have a look at that?

Answer (score 1):

Both are commonly used.

**Wondering if it is too late** is straightforward - "is too late" is the present tense, and it's being used to describe a situation in the present, so everything is as you'd expect.

**Wondering if it was too late** is harder to explain.  The most succinct reasoning is on [this page from the British Council](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/past-tense), which simply states that the past tense can be used "for politeness".  [This question and answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/167032/there-is-a-current-trend-of-using-past-tense-when-meaning-present-tense) go into it in more detail.

But the sentence you have is more complex than that. I think you might be asking whether the two tenses have to agree: whether the bold words in "I **was** wondering if it **was** too late" have to match.

If so, the answer is no.  When you're using the past tense in the normal way, there's no need for them to match - "I am wondering if it was raining yesterday" is clearly perfectly fine - and so there's no reason why they'd have to match when the past tense is being used for politeness alone.

By the way, **I was wondering if it was not too late** is quite formal and stilted.  You'd normally contract **was not** to **wasn't** (and the same with **isn't**).  It would also be perfectly common to say **I was wondering if it was too late** or **I was wondering if it's too late**, hoping for the answer "no".